# Display array content in a List Widget Qt C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring

i want to display some of the content of my array in a List Widget (item based) with Qt and C++, i tried this, but it dosent work :

```
QString exemple[2] = 'blablabla'
ui->listWidgetResult->addItem(exemple[2].toStdString().c_str());
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

This can't work:

```
QString example[2] = 'blablabla'
```

First, `'` is for `char` values, not for strings. Second, you are declaring an array of two QStrings, but assign it to a C string. What you mean is perhaps this:

```
QString example[2] = {"blabla", "blabla"};
```

Which you can actually abbreviate to:

```
QString example[] = {"blabla", "blabla"};
```

To add each string of the array to your list widget, you need to add each one individually. Also, there's no need to convert to a C string. QListWidget::addItem() takes QStrings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(example); ++i) {
    ui->listWidgetResult->addItem(exemple[i]);
}
```

Or, if you have a recent compiler that supports C++-11:

```
for (const auto& str : example) {
    ui->listWidgetResult->addItem(str);
}
```

Finally, instead of using plain arrays to hold your QStrings, you should instead consider holding them in a QStringList. You can then simply pass the whole QStringList using `addItems()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be an easy solution to what you are asking for.

```
void MyClass::Set_List(QList<QString> filesList, int item_count)
{
    QVector<QString> load_set(item_count);
    for(int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)
    {
        load_set[i] = filesList[i];
        ui -> listWidget -> addItem(load_set[i]);
    }
}
```

Then to get the info back out...

```
void MyClass::Selection(QListWidgestItem * item)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)
    {
        if(ui -> listWidget -> item(i) == item)
        {
            str = ui -> listWidget -> item(i) -> text();
        }
    }
}
```