# How to compare two QString arrays Qt C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qt-designer, qstring

i want to compare two QString Array with Qt and C++, i tried this, but it dosent work, (in fact my application crash...) :

```
if(ArrayOne[nb] != ArrayTwo[nb]){

}
```

And then i need to assign a value at an element of my array, but i dosent work too :

```
ArrayOne[nb] = ArrayTwo[nb];
```

To reach this :

```
if(ArrayOne[nb] != ArrayTwo[nb]){
ArrayOne[nb] = ArrayTwo[nb];
}
```

THANKS !

Comment: How are ArrayOne and ArratTwo declared? What is nb?

Comment: nb is an int, arrayone and two are declared like that : QString ArrayOne;

Comment: Also, what exactly does "doesn't work" imply? Does it not compile? Does it compile but behave differently than you expected? Differently how?

Comment: Use `QStringList`, it's a lot easier.

Comment: Yes it compile, i have edited my post : "(in fact my application crash...)"

Comment: OK, what value is in the strings? What value does nb have? If nb is larger than the string size (or equal to it) you will get undefined behavior (which includes crash)

Comment: Also, QString ArrayOne; is not an array of Qstrings, it's simply a QString

Comment: the int nb is generated like that : qrand() % ((high + 1) - low) + low; low and hight are between 1 and 10

Comment: Have you tried [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)?

Comment: We can found string with ten caracters in the array

Comment: with strcmp values must be constant char...

Comment: Judging from your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367458/display-array-content-in-a-list-widget-qt-c question, it seems you don't understand the basic workings of arrays in C++. I'd suggest you pick some beginner's tutorial for C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nb` value is probably outside the range for the size of your QString. i.e., nb > ArrayOne.size-1.

Comment: The nb value is between 1 and 10

Comment: But what is the content of ArrayOne?

Answer (score 1):

You say you have:

```
QString ArrayOne;
```

If this is true, then you are just comparing characters in two strings, not string arrays, at position `nb`. And QString's `operator[]` does not check range, so if `nb` is more than length of QString, program may very well crash, especially if you assign to invalid reference returned by `QString::operator[]`...

So, to be clear: your code probably crashes because `nb >= ArrayOne.length()`